# How to modify format of time in AM and PM in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, strftime

I have code in Python Pandas like below:

```
print("Date: ", datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S"))
```

And it generates result: `Date:  14-09-2021 08:36:23`

Nevertheless, I would like to have something like `Date:  14-09-2021 20:36:23`.
So at AM I would like to have time like `08:22:13` and so on and at PM I prefer to have format of time like: `20:22:13`.

How can I modify my code above to achieve result as I need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%I indicates 12 hour format. I believe to solve your issue you have to switch %I to %H (24 hour format).